# Subgroup generated by a reflection is not normal in the dihedral group of order $2n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

Let $D_{2n}$ be the dihedral group of order $2n$. Then, the subgroup generated by a reflection is not normal.

I think I've come up with a proof for a converse that if an element is not $\left\langle h\right\rangle$ for $H$ the subgroup consisting of $n$ rotations, then its square equals the identity thus it is a reflection.

However, I am struggling to prove why a reflection would not be normal in this case. Is this because a reflection $y\in Y$ for $g \in G$ would not give $ghg^{-1}\in Y$ because we have the property $y^2=e$?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You are correct that any element that is not a rotation is of order $2$. But in **any** group, for elements $x$ and $y$, the orders of $x$ and $yxy^{-1}$ are always the same. So if $y$ is a reflection, and $g$ is any element, then $gyg^{-1}$ will *necessarily* have order $2$. But you want to show that you can find a $g$ for which $gyg^{-1}\neq y$, so that it cannot be in $\langle y\rangle = \{1,y\}$.

Comment: Keep in mind: your goal is not to prove that "a reflection would not be normal", instead your goal is to prove that the subgroup generated by a reflection is not normal. So to start with, given a reflection $y \in D_{2n}$, can you say what is the subgroup generated by $y$?

Comment: Also exclude the case $n=1$ and $n=2$. For those the subgroup generated by the reflection is normal. If $s$ is the reflection and $r$ the rotation, then $r^{-1}sr=r^{-2}s$. If in turn, this is $s$, then $r^2=1$. Therefore, $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Comment: @arturo-magidin I may have come up with one: Let a cyclic subgroup generated by rotation $y$, then $\langle y\rangle =\{1,y\}$. Suppose $y_1$ is some other reflection. Then, $(y_1)^{-1} y y_1 \neq s$, hence it is not normal.

Comment: @krn08 What is $s$? Is that supposed to be $y$? Your claim is not necessarily true. In the dihedral group of order $8$, putting the square as having corners at $(\pm 1,0)$ and $(0,\pm 1)$, the reflections about the $x$ and $y$ axes commute. So you can find reflections different from $y$ for which $(y_1)^{-1}yy_1=y$. In short: your argument is at best incomplete, and very likely just plain wrong.

Comment: @arturo-magidin Yes, it is a typo it is y instead of s. I may have found one - if $hyh^{-1}\notin \langle y\rangle$

Answer (score 1):

Note $\mathcal R_n\cap\langle h\rangle=\{e\}$ where $h$ is a reflection symmetry in the dihedral group $\mathcal D_n$ and where $\mathcal R_n$ denotes the $\mathcal D_n$ subgroup of all rotation symmetries. Since $\mathcal R_n\lhd\mathcal D_n$ then we have $$h\in\mathcal Z(\mathcal D_n)\iff\langle h\rangle\lhd\mathcal D_n\implies\mathcal D_n=\mathcal R_n\oplus\langle h\rangle$$ As $\mathcal D_n$ is non-abelian it is not the product of abelian groups and thus $\langle h\rangle$ is not normal in $\mathcal D_n$.